# Control widget's width programmatically

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to integrate a progress bar to my app. I use a **table** to display the *assignments items*. Inside the **table row**, I have a **label** inside a **horizontal panel**. The label width is set to 0 inside the **layout** options. I'm getting the desired label width percent from another widget and the label **onAttach** event has the following code:

```
function setProgress(){  

  var percent = widget.parent.parent.descendants.Label8.text;      
  widget.getElement().setAttribute("width", percent);
  //widget.getElement().width = percent;
  //this.widget.getElement().setAttribute("width", percent);    

}

setProgress();
```

The above is not working at all. If I use JQuery, it works by doing the following:

```
function setProgress(){  

  var percent = widget.parent.parent.descendants.Label8.text;          
  $(".app-DashboardAdmin-Label9").css("width", percent);

}

setProgress();
```

The problem is that by using JQuery, the width of the progress bar for all the items in the table is the same. I assume the only possible way would be to create styles that would match all the possible percent outcomes and match them accordingly. That would require me to create around 50 styles and then do following:

```
function setProgress(){  

  var percent = widget.parent.parent.descendants.Label8.text;          

  if(percent === "0%") {
    widget.styles = ["zeropercent"];
  } else if (percent === "10%"){
      widget.styles = ["tenpercent"];
  } else if (percent === "12.5%"){
      widget.styles = ["12pointfivepercent"];
  } else if (percent === "15%"){
      widget.styles = ["fifteenpercent"];
  } etc, etc, etc.

}

setProgress();
```

Now, that is a lot of hassle to achieve a very simple thing. Is there any suggestion that you can give or should I just give up on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this:

[image]

- Add an onDataLoad handler for the label

  ```
  drawProgress(widget);
  ```
- Add style `progress` to the label and set its width to 100.
- In a client script (modify the first line to capture your data):

  ```
  function drawProgress(widget){
    var progress=widget.datasource.item.progress;
    var div=widget.getElement();
    div.innerText='';
    var innerDiv=document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.setAttribute('class','progress-bar');
    innerDiv.setAttribute('style','width:'+progress+'px');
    div.appendChild(innerDiv);
  }
  ```
- Add to styles:

  ```
  .progress-bar{
    background-color: navy;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .app-Label.progress{
     border: 1px solid silver;
  }
  ```

Comment: You genius! Thank you so much. I modified your implementation so that it fit mines and it is working great!

Answer (score 0):

One interesting solution for creating a progress bar in App Maker is to use the star rating widget with some custom CSS. Instead of showing stars for the rating, you can show a circle or square and get something that looks like a progress bar, e.g. you can create a progress bar variant for the star rating widget:

```
.app-StarRating--ProgressBar .app-StarRating-Star {
   color:blue;
   font-family: Arial;
}

.app-StarRating--ProgressBar .app-StarRating-Star::after {
  content: '\25AE';
}
```

You can then set the value of the star rating widget to indicate the level of progress.